# How do I enable image auto-updating in LXD?

Tags: lxd

When I installed LXD, I disabled image auto-updating since I knew I was going to be traveling and using slow internet connections for a week or so.

Now that I'm back home with a fast connection, I'd like to turn auto-update back on. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable auto-update on a per-image basis by editing the config with

`lxc image edit <img>`

and setting `auto_update: true` as a top-level item in the config

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case, `auto_update: true` was already set on the individual images; it was just that during `lxd init` the overall auto-update mechanism was disabled. It was a little tricky figuring out what `<img>` meant; I did `lxc image list` and found that I could edit them by fingerprint, but does the fingerprint change over time?

Answer (score 1):

Information about LXD image handling can be found [here, in the docs](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/image-handling).

When you disable image auto-update using `lxd init`, the consequence can be seen by running `lxc config show`:

```
$ lxc config show
config:
  images.auto_update_interval: "0"
```

To reset to the default (update the images every six hours), this can be unset as follows:

```
$ lxc config unset images.auto_update_interval
```